# let $z$ be a complex number such that $|z+9|=3|z+1|$. Find $|z|$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am fairly new with complex number. I tried to do $|z+9|^2 = 9|z+1|^2$ and solved for everything and ended with $|z| = \sqrt(-9)$  I believe that is indeed the solution but I have it just seems fishy to me.

Comment: $|z|$ is always a non-negative real number.

Comment: Thank! figured out where I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$. Then,
$$|z+9|=3|z+1|\Rightarrow |x+iy+9|=3|x+iy+1|$$
$$\Rightarrow |(x+9)+iy|=3|(x+1)+iy| $$
then,
$$ \sqrt{(x+9)^2+y^2}=9\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+18x+81+y^2=9x^2+18x+9+9y^2 $$

$$\Rightarrow 8x^2+8y^2=72 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=9$$
Then, we have:

$$|z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{9}=3. $$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&9|z+1|^2-|z+9|^2=9(z+1)(\bar{z}+1)-(z+9)(\bar{z}+9)\\
&=&9(|z|^2+z+\bar{z}+1)-[|z|^2+9(z+\bar{z})+81]\\
&=&8|z|^2-72=8(|z|^2-9)=8(|z|-3)(|z|+3),
\end{eqnarray}
hence $|z|=3$.